# How can I retrieve the mount namespace of the current task in a BPF program using GCP's 4.15 kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, google-cloud-platform, kernel, bpf

I am trying to retrieve the mount namespace of the current task in a [BPF program](https://github.com/dippynark/kubecast/blob/master/bpf/bpf_tty.c) as follows:

```
task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
bpf_probe_read(&nsproxy, sizeof(nsproxy), (void *)&task->nsproxy);
bpf_probe_read(&mnt_ns, sizeof(mnt_ns), (void *)&nsproxy->mnt_ns);
bpf_probe_read(&ns, sizeof(ns), (void *)&mnt_ns->ns);
mnt_ns_inum = ns.inum;
```

This works fine using an Ubuntu kernel (`uname -r`: 4.15.0-13-generic) and `mnt_ns_inum` gets a value of 4026531840 for tasks in the host's mount namespace but running the same code using GCP's kernel (`uname -r`: 4.15.0-1019-gcp) always sets `mnt_ns_inum` to 0.

I am at a loss as to what Google could have changed to cause this behaviour (I am testing this on a local VM so the only difference between the two cases is the kernel I have booted the VM with and the kernel headers used for compilation).

Additionally, this same code worked for a GCP 4.13 kernel (`uname -r`: 4.13.0-1008-gcp) so it seems that this is a recent change.

EDIT:

For the 4.15 GCP kernel, the return values for the calls to `bpf_probe_read` are as follows:

- 0
- 18446744073709551602
- 18446744073709551602

As mentioned in the comments below, the non-zero return values correspond to `-EFAULT`.

Comment: Could you check which calls to `bpf_probe_read` return a non-zero integer? The number should give us an indication of the cause.

Comment: The call itself doesn't return a non-zero integer, the vaule of `mnt_ns_inum` is zero as a result of running those commands - will clarify the question

Comment: Ah sorry, a misunderstanding on my part, will check the return values now

Comment: @pchaigno have added the return values

Comment: Those numbers equal `-EFAULT` so it looks like the address for `nsproxy->mnt_ns` is incorrect. Are you sure you're using the correct kernel headers?

Comment: I am fairly sure yeah, I have `uname -r`=4.15.0-1019-gcp and I'm using the include path `-I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1019-gcp/include -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1019-gcp/arch/x86/include -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1019-gcp/arch/x86/include/generated -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1019-gcp/include/generated/uapi -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1019-gcp/arch/x86/include/uapi -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1019-gcp/include/uapi` for my clang compilation

Comment: also as a smoke test for my process, this has worked for a number of other kernel versions including Ubuntu's kernel of the same version - thanks for narrowing down where the issue is coming from though, will keep trying

Comment: The full code including build process is here if you're interested https://github.com/dippynark/kubecast/tree/master/bpf

Comment: I guess you already checked it's not that issue: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/1548 :-)
It should cause issues with 4.13 not 4.15 but it never hurts to check (I guess you already did since you were the one to open it).

Comment: Haha yeah I've added that struct to the top of my program, the same process worked for Ubuntu's 4.15 kernel so I think it is something Google specific

Comment: One last idea: Could you run `offsetof(struct task_struct, nsproxy)` in your BPF program and retrieve the returned value in userspace? Same with `offsetof(struct nsproxy, mnt_ns)`. That would help check if it's even an issue with the validity of pointers.

Comment: `offsetof(struct task_struct, nsproxy)=2776` and `offsetof(struct nsproxy, mnt_ns)=24` - is that expected?