# Can I use a previous GCP Ubuntu OS version on GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Due to an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568585/how-can-i-retrieve-the-mount-namespace-of-the-current-task-in-a-bpf-program-usin) I found when running the latest GCP Ubuntu OS, I want to spin up a cluster using an older OS version (preferably with `uname -r`: 4.13.0-1008-gcp).

Is this possible on GKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, its not possible to use an older Ubuntu OS version in Kubernetes Cluster.